# Switch setup to power on/off PC

Tags: arduino, switches, pc

I have a project which contains a PC connected to an Arduino R4. The PC is enclosed in a cabinet and I can't open it (easily) to power it on. Normally I would run a remote wire to the button to power-on, but the PC does not have header pin to connect the button (only a soldered push button).

My question, anyone have an idea how to setup a push button on the outside of the cabinet. The button would power on the PC by supplying the required 12-volt power. After shutdown of the PC by normal means (ie: Start menu), the 12 volt power would then be cut-off. This would allow pressing the button again to power the PC back up.

Pressing the button while the PC is running should do nothing, or if pressed and held for a few seconds it would cut power (basically same a normal PC button).

I thought of various tactics, such a latching relays and/or buttons; but nothing I have come up with can accomplish both powering on the PC and cutting the power once shutdown. Also, the Arduino is powered via USB from the PC, so once it shuts down, the Arduino of course shuts down.

I can power the Arduino using a separate 5 volt power supply, but I'd really like to not have another power supply nor to leave the Arduino running indefinitely.

Another option is to unsolder the PC switch and replace with a terminal block. I am a rookie (at best) with electronic soldering, so this is my absolute last resort.

Comment: Set it to power on automatically when mains is present in the bios. Then add an on/off rocker switch on the mains.